# Logic and urn with balls of different colors.

Tags: logic

I'm sorry if the community to place such a question is chosen incorrectly, but I think math is quite suitable for this case. So there are two reasoning/logic questions.

*[temporary deleted]*

Comment: I agree. For Q1, 3 and 4 are correct. For Q2 5 is correct.

Comment: Q1 : 1, 3, 4 are correct. Q2 only 5 is correct (the black ball could alone)

Comment: But there is can be only one right answer, guys! :)

Comment: Probably the test asks something like "pick the most informative/stronger answer"? In any case, I'd answer Q1 with 4. (And yes, this should be made clear by the test.)